# Rails I18n :many :other :count problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I often have problems with translations. I remember this had to do with some translations using :many, but yet when I see an error message like this

```
translation data {:one=>"1 month", :other=>"%{count} months"} can not be used with :count => 3
```

...it shouldn't make any sense, isn't `:other` supposed to handle all other cases ??

**EDIT** for the english version, I'm using the default english files, so in this particular case, [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml)

**EDIT** my working French translation looks like this

```
datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      about_x_hours:
        one:   "environ une heure"
        many: "environ %{count} heures"
      about_x_months:
        one:   "environ un mois"
        many: "environ %{count} mois"
      about_x_years:
        one:   "environ un an"
        many: "environ %{count} ans"
      almost_x_years:
        one:   "presqu'un an"
        many: "presque %{count} ans"
      half_a_minute: "une demi-minute"
      less_than_x_minutes:
        zero:  "moins d'une minute"
        one:   "moins d'une minute"
        many: "moins de %{count} minutes"
      less_than_x_seconds:
        zero:  "moins d'une seconde"
        one:   "moins d'une seconde"
        many: "moins de %{count} secondes"
      over_x_years:
        one:   "plus d'un an"
        many: "plus de %{count} ans"
      x_days:
        one:   "1 jour"
        many: "%{count} jours"
      x_minutes:
        one:   "1 minute"
        many: "%{count} minutes"
      x_months:
        one:   "1 mois"
        many: "%{count} mois"
      x_seconds:
        one:   "1 seconde"
        many: "%{count} secondes"
```

As you can see, I had to replace `other` by `many` to make it work, but I would like to understand WHY.

Comment: how your localization file looks like?

Comment: Have you supplied any of your own translations or is this an issue with the defaults?

Comment: Also does calling this `I18n.translate('datetime.distance_in_words.x_months', count: 3)`  work as expected?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't (with the English default)